# Получаю данные через Jquery но когда хочу отобразить пишет Object object D

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот такой небольшой скрипт получаю данные из `html` и хочу передать их затем в карту но в `alert()`выводится `Object object` ,а не мое значение как это исправть ребята?
Вот мой кодик

```
var map;
var x= -34.397;
var his=$('td').eq(19).each(function(){
   console.log($(this).html());
});

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat:x, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
};

alert(his);
initMap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
var map;
var x= -34.397;
var his = $('td').eq(19).html();

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat:x, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
};

alert(his());
initMap();
```

У вас выводился сам объект `td` к которому вы обращались. Нужно, что бы выводилось значение функции

Comment: Yuri сколько лет у вас практики на js и jquery

Comment: @elik, 2-3 года. А что?

Comment: Просто интересно .любопытсв)

Comment: Нее несработало Он вернулд такой ответ function {

Comment: function() {
   return $('td').eq(19).html();
};

Comment: почему так стало ?

Comment: @elik, потому что надо было вызвать функцию: `alert(his());`

Comment: @elik, всё, я поправил. Спасибо Grundy. Теперь всё работать будет

Comment: Что за grundy?)

Comment: @elik, пользователь. Он выше в комментариях вам ответил

Comment: Да сработало )Юрий такой вопрос эти данные плученнеы я могу вставить в  map,? это координат

Comment: Ой да не заметил0)Спасибо Grundy !благодарен !

Comment: @Yuri, в принципе тут функция-то и не нужна можно было сразу значение получать

Comment: можно пример грундий

Comment: @elik, [`html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)  возвращает строку, в некоторых случаях может потребоваться приведение к числу руками

Comment: @elik, `var his = $('td').eq(19).html();`, и так как тебе значение строка - то при передаче в алерт `()` не нужны: `alert(his)`

Comment: ааа понел понел

Comment: я сам с Java перешел чем то языки похожи но джава строо типизировнная там надо делать привения а у скрипта как то полегче поэтому пока путаюсь

Comment: @Grundy, оу, точно. Ну тот пример ему для общего развития